# Using new on void pointer

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    void* Foo = new???
    delete Foo;
}
```

How do you do something like the above? You can't put `new void[size]`. And I don't want to know how to do it with `malloc()` and `free()`. I already know that works. I'm curious and want to know how it's done with new and delete.

I googled this and saw something about `operator new(size)`; and `operator delete(size)`;

What is the difference between those and `new` / `delete`? Why does C++ not just allow new `void* [size]`?

Comment: Why do you want a `void *` in C++?

Comment: I'm just curious because I see it being done in C. In C, I saw someone do void* Foo = malloc(size);  It's the same thing no?

Comment: No it's not. In C++ `new type[3]` allocates 3 times the size of type where malloc would have to look something like this: `malloc(3*sizeof(type))`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
int main()
{
    void* Foo = ::operator new(N);
    ::operator delete(Foo);
}
```

These operators allocate/deallocate raw memory measured in bytes, just like `malloc`.

Answer (score 23):

> Why does C++ not just allow new void[size]?

Because `void` is not an object; it has no size!  How much space should be allocated?  Bear in mind that `new T[size]` is **approximately** equivalent to `malloc(sizeof(T) * size)`.

If you just want a raw byte array, then you could use `char`.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>* Although, of course, because this is C++ you should use something like `std::vector<char>` to avoid memory-leak and exception-safety issues.</sub>

Comment: Ok but why does Malloc allow it then? Void is still not an object in C.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: `malloc` does not allow this... The analogous\ `malloc` invokation would be `malloc(sizeof(void)*N)`, which will not compile.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: It doesn't "allow" it; `malloc` is not typesafe; in order to be able to assign it to any pointer type, it needs to return a `void *`.

Comment: I **don't** think raw memory should use `new char[n]`: the allocated memory contains objects of type `char`. Raw memory is allocated using `operator new(n)` or `operator new[](n)` (or using suitable allocator members).

Answer (score 13):

C++ travels in constructed objects allocated using some variation of `new T`. or `new T[n]` for some type `T`. If you really need uninitialized memory (it is very rare that you do), you can allocate/deallocate it using `operator new()` and `operator delete()`:

```
void* ptr = operator new(size);
operator delete(ptr);
```

(similarily for the array forms)

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
void* data = new char[num_of_bytes];
```

to allocate some memory, in a similar fashion as malloc

Answer (score 2):

`void *` is convertible to any pointer type. You can simply do `void *Foo = new int` or any other type that you want. But there really isn't a reason to do this in C++.